# Using InAppBrowser on click?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

I keep trying to find a tutorial for this but all the tutorials I seem to run into are for loading a web page on load. I want to load a url when activated in the InAppBrowser from cordova. If you guys could point me in the right direction to accomplish this I would much appreciate it! Here is the onload code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


        function onDeviceReady() {
            var ref = window.open('http://AcademyMusicGroup.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
            ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
            ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });
        }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take the window.open out side of the onDeviceReady() function

Comment: because that function is called when the app first starts

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether that's what you want or not ...

But if you want the browser to pop up on click

Html:

```
        <button onclick="PopUpBrowser();">PopUp</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);


        function PopUpBrowser() {
            var ref = window.open('http://AcademyMusicGroup.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
            /*ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function() { alert('start: ' + event.url); });
            ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function() { alert('stop: ' + event.url); });
            ref.addEventListener('exit', function() { alert(event.type); });*/ Depends on whether you need them or not ... 
        }

        </script>
```